# What does the forward slash mean within a JavaScript regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

I can't find any definitive information on what `/` means in a JavaScript regex.

The code `replace(/\r/g, '');`

What I'm able to figure out is this:

- `/`  = I don't know
- `\r` = carriage return
- `/g` = I don't know but It may mean 'the match must occur at the point where the previous match ended.'

Comment: You should read the manuals first: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions.

Comment: Read this: http://www.regular-expressions.info/ - you'll be glad you did.. :-)

Comment: @techfoobar regular-expressions.info isn't online anymore :/

Comment: @piperchester, that site still works for me, though it did take a very long time to load just now.  And it *can't* go away, that's probably the most common external link in regex-tagged Q/A's.  We'd be lost without it! :P

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/ is working pretty well fior me too..

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The slashes indicate the start and end of the regular expression.

The `g` at the end is a flag and indicates it is a global search.

From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Regular_Expressions#Advanced_Searching_With_Flags):

> Regular expressions have four optional flags that allow for global and
>   case insensitive searching. To indicate a global search, use the g
>   flag. To indicate a case-insensitive search, use the i flag. To
>   indicate a multi-line search, use the m flag. To perform a "sticky"
>   search, that matches starting at the current position in the target
>   string, use the y flag. These flags can be used separately or together
>   in any order, and are included as part of the regular expression.
>
> To include a flag with the regular expression, use this syntax:

```
 var re = /pattern/flags;
```

Answer (score 15):

To add a little more detail, the `/` characters are part of the regular expression [literal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_(computer_programming)) syntax in JavaScript/ECMAScript. The `/` characters are used during [lexical analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) to determine that a regular expression pattern is present between them and anything immediately following them will be regular expression flags.  The [ECMAScript standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.8.5) has defined this in [EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form), for your perusual:

> RegularExpressionLiteral :: / RegularExpressionBody /
>   RegularExpressionFlags

A good analogy for the `/` in regular expressions is the `"` or `'` that surround string literals in JavaScript.

Answer (score 9):

As others have pointed out, you should read the docs!  That said:

Think of the forward slash as quotation marks for regular expressions.  The slashes contain the expression but are not themselves part of the expression. (If you want to test for a forward slash, you have to escape it with a backwards slash.) The lowercase g specifies that this is a global search, i.e., find all matches rather than stopping at the first match.

Answer (score 6):

As is indicated [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Regular_Expressions#Advanced_Searching_With_Flags), the forward slashes are not a part of the expression itself, but denote the beginning and ending of the expression.

Comment: It might be helpful, in the future, to include a small excerpt with your answer, in case the linked content is no longer accessible.

Answer (score 2):

To add to metadept's answer:

the g bit is the global indicator - see [What does the regular expression /_/g mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6052616/what-does-the-regular-expression-g-mean) - i.e. replace all occurrences, not just the first one