# Regular expression for decimals that are accepted in decimal.Parse

Tags: c#, regex, search, text, decimal

The desired result is a pattern for positive inputs that doesn't throw an exception in `decimal.Parse` and doesn't accept the `01`-model-like inputs.

Valid inputs:

```
1
1.2
.2
1.
```

Invalid inputs:

```
01
01.2
.
1.B
A.2
A
A.
```

I liked the pattern in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3068537/3602352) (`-?(0|([1-9]\d*))(\.\d+)?`); but somehow (as mentioned in the comment), it accepts `X.2` (only with `Regex.IsMatch`) and negative decimals, and rejects `1.`; so I modified it to `/((0|([1-9]\d*))(\.\d*)?)|(\.\d+)/g`, and it worked perfectly in [regexr.com](http://regexr.com/) and also [RegExr v1](http://regexr.com/v1/); but I got no luck with `Regex.IsMatch`.

Any suggestions? and why doesn't the pattern work with `Regex.IsMatch` while it works somewhere else?

Comment: what about 0.5? Is this a valid input?

Comment: Do the answers below answer your question? If yes, please accept the one that works.

Comment: Try [`Regex.IsMatch(str, @"^(?!0)(?:\d+\.?\d*|\.\d+)$")`](http://ideone.com/hTSHXp). See regex [demo](https://regex101.com/r/yG4bQ1/1).

Comment: @MaheshChand; Yes it is.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew; I apologize for being late. The pattern works perfectly; if you post an answer, I'd up-vote it (best answer already chosen).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This passes all your tests:

```
var reg = new Regex("^(([1-9]*[0-9](\\.|(\\.[0-9]*)?))|(\\.[0-9]+))$");

(reg.IsMatch("1") == true).Dump();
(reg.IsMatch("1.2") == true).Dump();
(reg.IsMatch(".2") == true).Dump();
(reg.IsMatch("1.") == true).Dump();

(reg.IsMatch("01") == false).Dump();
(reg.IsMatch("01.2") == false).Dump();
(reg.IsMatch(".") == false).Dump();
(reg.IsMatch("1.B") == false).Dump();
(reg.IsMatch("A.2") == false).Dump();
(reg.IsMatch("A") == false).Dump();
(reg.IsMatch("A.") == false).Dump();
```

Explanation:

We try to capture as many 1-9 numbers as we can. This excludes leading 0s. We then allow any number before the decimal point.

Then we have three cases: No decimal point, a decimal point, a decimal point with numbers following it.

Otherwise, if we start with a decimal point, we allow any number, but at least one after it. This excludes `.`

Answer (score 0):

You've to remove '/' character at the beginning. Since it's the syntax of regular expression to specify the start of regex in Javascript/ECMAScript but not c#.(Refer: [What does the forward slash mean within a JavaScript regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15661969/what-does-the-forward-slash-mean-within-a-javascript-regular-expression)) Thus, final regex is

```
((0|([1-9]\d*))(\.\d*)?)|(\.\d+)/g
```

[image]

Comment: Well! it worked with the valid inputs; but with the invalid ones, it did accept:  `01`, `01.2`, `1.B` and `A.2`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this simple regex should do the job perfectly well `/-?(0?\.\d+|[1-9]\d*\.?\d*)/g`

You haven't asked for it but it also handles the negatives. If not needed just delete the `-?` at the beginning and make it even more simpler.

Comment: I removed the `-?`; it returned `false` with all inputs mentioned in the question.

Comment: Please check it at http://regexr.com/3d4va with your inputs... With or without  using `-?` in the front

Comment: The pattern mentioned in your comment works fine although it's different from that one in your answer; however, thanks for your effort.