# lark grammar: How does the escaped string regex work?

Tags: python, regex, grammar, lark-parser

The lark parser predefines some common terminals, including a string. It is defined as follows:

```
_STRING_INNER: /.*?/
_STRING_ESC_INNER: _STRING_INNER /(?<!\\)(\\\\)*?/ 

ESCAPED_STRING : "\"" _STRING_ESC_INNER "\""
```

I do understand `_STRING_INNER`. I also understand how `ESCAPED_STRING` is composed. But what I don't really understand is `_STRING_ESC_INNER`.

If I read the regex correctly, all it says is that whenever I find two consecutive literal backslashes, they must not be preceeded by another literal backslash?

How can I combine those two into a single regex?

And wouldn't it be required for the grammar to only allow escaped double quotes in the string data?

Comment: why does `_STRING_INNER` have two backslashes? in `/.*?/`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Preliminaries:

- `.*?` Non-greedy match, meaning the shortest possible number of repetitions of `.` (any symbol). This only makes sense when followed by something else. So `.*?X` on input `AAXAAX` would match only the `AAX` part, instead of expanding all the way to the last `X`.
- `(?<!...)` is a "negative look-behind assertion" ([link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)): "Matches if the current position in the string is not preceded by a match for ....". So `.*(?<!X)Y` would match `AY` but not `XY`.

Applying this to your example:

- `ESCAPED_STRING`: The rule says: "Match `"`, then `_STRING_ESC_INNER`, and then `"` again".
- `_STRING_INNER`: Matches the shortest possible number of repetitions of any symbol. As said before, this only makes sense when considering the regular expression that comes after it.
- `_STRING_ESC_INNER`: We want this to match the shortest possible string that does not contain a closing quote. That is, for an input `"abc"xyz"`, we want to match `"abc"`, instead of also consuming the `xyz"` part. However, we have to make sure that the `"` is really a closing quote, in that it should not be itself escaped. So for input `"abc\"xyz"`, we do not want to match only `"abc\"`, because the `\"` is escaped. We observe that the closing `"` has to be directly preceded by an even number of `\` (with zero being an even number). So `"` is ok, `\\"` is ok, `\\\\"` is ok etc. But as soon as `"` is preceded by an odd number of `\`, that means the `"` is not really a closing quote.

  `(\\\\)` matches `\\`. The `(?<!\\)` says "the position before should not have `\`". So combined `(?<!\\)(\\\\)` means "match `\\`, but only if it is not preceded by `\`".

  The following `*?` then does the smallest possible repetitions of this, which again only makes sense when considering the regular expression that comes after this, which is the `"` from the `ESCAPED_STRING` rule (possible point of confusion: the `\"` in the `ESCAPED_STRING` refers to a literal `"` in the actual input we want to match, in the same way that `\\\\` refers to `\\` in the input). So `(?<!\\)(\\\\)*?\"` means "match the shortest amount of `\\` that is followed by `"` and not preceded by `\`. So in other words, `(?<!\\)(\\\\)*?\"` matches only `"` that are preceded by an even number of `\` (including blocks of size 0).

  Now combining it with the preceding `_STRING_INNER`, the `_STRING_ESC_INNER` rule then says: Match the *first* `"` preceded by an even number of `\`, so in other words, the first `"` where the `\` is not itself escaped.

Comment: Thanks. But why do we want to match an escaped quote `\"`? That basically means the string is not yet complete and there are more characters to be consumed.

Comment: Got it. When you write `\"` you actually mean the literal `"`, just in regex style so it has to be escaped.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, that was poorly worded on my part. I edited the answer to make it more clear. So the `\"` in the program code corresponds to a `"` in the input.

Comment: I'm also confused about `\`. why does `_STRING_INNER` have two backslashes? in `/.*?/`?

Comment: @CharlieParker I'm not fully sure what you mean? If your question is why there are two forward slashes in `_STRING_INNER: /.*?/`, this just the syntax for specifying a regular expression in Lark (https://lark-parser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/grammar.html#terminals). I guess this was chosen to make it easier to differentiate between regular strings (`"somestring"`) and regular expressions (`/someregex/`).

Comment: In general, you can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15661969/what-does-the-forward-slash-mean-within-a-javascript-regular-expression for some more background on this convention.