# Autocomplete the last incomplete phrase using regex in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a sentence which looks like below

```
term = "How much new sales in new"
```

Say I get a some suggestions like `New York, New Delhi, Papua New Guinea` and I select `New York`.

```
choice = "New York"
```

Now I need to ensure that any latest substring that matches the selection is replaced with the selection.

So ideally my string should now become

```
term = "How much new sales in New York"
```

So this is what I do

```
terms = term.split(/\s+/g)
choice_terms = choice.split(/\s+/g)
terms.pop() //remove the last substring since this is what the user typed last
check_terms = terms

// get the latest instance of first term of the selection
if(user_choice_terms.length > 1) {
    if(check_terms.lastIndexOf(user_choice_first_term) !== -1) {
            last_index = check_terms.lastIndexOf(user_choice_first_term)
            check_terms.splice(-last_index)            //remove anything after the matched index
            check_terms.push(...user_choice_terms)     //add the selected term
            return check_terms
    }
 }
```

But this doesn't seem like a reliable solution and I would rather use a `regex`. The user may also type like this

```
term = "How much new sales in new     yo"
```

Here I am guaranteed to get a suggestion `New York` against `yo` and should be replaced with `New York`

Is there any `regex` solution to ensure the latest substring match is completely replaced with the selection?

**Note:** I am using `jquery ui autocomplete`

Comment: Check out the meaning of `$` in regex. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8327705/what-are-and-in-regular-expressions)

Comment: @DanielF yes sure but I do not understand how will I handle `new       yo` even if I detect it.

Comment: `((\w+)?\ *\w+\ *)$` where group 1 (`\1`) will be your query term, where you replace all consecutive spaces with one single space before searching in your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may create a pattern that will match all possible prefixes of the `choice` with all spaces replaced with `\s+` pattern to match 1 or more whitespaces and adding `$` at the end of the pattern to only match at the end of the string:

```
/N(?:e(?:w(?:\s+(?:Y(?:o(?:r(?:k)?)?)?)?)?)?)?$/i
```

It will match `N`, `Ne`, `New`, etc. with any amount of whitespace between `New` and `York`, and only at the end of the string due to `$`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XOnvFc/1)

See JavaScript demo:

```js
const make_prefix = (string) => {
    let s = string.charAt(0);
    for (let i=1; i<string.length; i++) {
        s += "(?:" + string.charAt(i);
    }
    for (let i=1; i<string.length; i++) {
        s += ")?";
    }
    return s;
}

const term = "How much new sales in new      yo";
const choice = "New York";
const regex = new RegExp(make_prefix(choice).replace(/\s+/g, '\\s+') + '$', 'i');
console.log(term.replace(regex, choice))
// => How much new sales in New York
```

Comment: this solution is great. But can you put a check whether the replacement is successful or not? In other words whether prefix matched or not. I plan to trigger another piece of code incase the prefix didn't match.

Comment: @SouvikRay You may use `if (regex.test(term)) { term = term.replace(regex, choice); } else { /* FALLBACK IF NO MATCH */ }`

Comment: hello! There is a problem with the regex. If my term is `name` and choice is `endice name` ,then the final term is `namendice name` instead of `name endice name`. Can you check?

Comment: @SouvikRay It appears to me that there should be no match in this case, you need to match at word boundary, `const regex = new RegExp("\\b" + make_prefix(choice).replace(/\s+/g, '\\s+') + '$', 'i');`

Comment: yes this seems to have fixed the problem. Needed to add a word boundry. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi Wiktor. I need your help once again. Do you think the regex can be improved to consider a situation where the the ending characters may not be related to the suggestions? For example `const term = "How much new sales in new      yo abcd";` `const choice = "New York";` Here you can see the `term` ends with some characters `abcd` and the match fails. Do you think the regex can be improved to look for latest substring irrespective how the `term` ends?

Comment: @SouvikRay Probably something like `new RegExp("\\b" + make_prefix(choice).replace(/\s+/g, '\\s+') + '(?!.*\\b' + make_prefix(choice).replace(/\s+/g, '\\s+') + ')' , 'i');`

Comment: hi Wiktor I have tried this and this works for me. Thanks again!